# How to prevent matching inside ""?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using [this](https://regex101.com/r/cjtpMI/4) regex to implement .? operator in javascript.

The construction of it is `varible.?key action?:value if key is null or undefined`.

These are some valid examples:
`foo.?bar() : "bar is not defined"`
`(foo.bar!=null&&foo.bar!=undefined?foo.bar():"bar is not defined")`

`foo.?bar.x : foo.bar.y`
`(foo.bar!=null&&foo.bar!=undefined?foo.bar.x:foo.bar.y)`

And i have to prevent matching this:
`"foo.?bar.x : foo.bar.y"`
`"'foo.?bar.x : foo.bar.y'`
`` `foo.?bar.x : foo.bar.y` ``

while still matching this:
`` `my favourite foo value is ${foo.?bar.x : foo.bar.y} ` ``

My question is can it be solved with regex, or maybe should it be solved partially by regex and some other form?
Maybe split it into smaller strings?
What you suggest?
Maybe there are other ways to implement it more efficiently? If yes how can I do this?

Comment: Try to add a dash `^` before everything, at the beginning and ` sign inside the regex body. ^([^-=\s+*\/;)"`]\S+)\s*\.\?\s*([\w\d]+)(.*?)\s*:\s*([^-=\s+*\/;]+)

Comment: but then `1 + foo.?bar.x : foo.bar.y` wont work it should be treated as expresion.

Comment: What is this .? operator you speak of and where does it originate?

Comment: `object` .? has property if yes do something with it else return value
`object.?key() : "this function coud return something important but ther's no function so I'm here"`

Comment: @zsawyer This operator does not exist, but asuming `.` means acces key in object then `.?` would mean acces key in object if key is found and if not   do something else like i shown its just shortcut for not writing `(object.key != null && object.key != undefined ? object.key() : "expresion")` == `object.?key():"expresion"`